# Never allow upgrade notices on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, kiosk

I have some digital "bulletin boards" around the office that are just TVs set up as computer displays, running Firefox.  No interface of any kind, just for viewing. I run it on Firefox because it has an add-on for automatically going to fullscreen (no toolbars) when the app starts.

The problem is that Firefox occasionally updates itself, and then instead of going back to its home page (the bulletin board) it shows this self-congratulatory "we updated Firefox" page; and I have to go around to each board, plug in the mouse, and dismiss the thing.  Happened at the beginning of this weekend (Thanksgiving) so the stupid update message was displayed for three days!

Is there any way to set Firefox so it never, **ever** shows any kind of notices of this type?  The current version doesn't seem to even have a "do not update" setting; just "update automatically" or "tell me when an update is available" (which will also be a notice I don't want).

Alternatively, I suppose I could use a different browser, so long as I avoid these same issues.  (But not IE!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to `about:config` in the address bar of Firefox you can tweak some advanced settings.

Change **app.update.silent** to **true** then close and restart Firefox

*Note*: This will probably silence all update prompts from Firefox so make sure you're manually checking for updates at least monthly.

Comment: I'll check it out.  The actualy Mozilla documentation for the setting appears to be quite outdated; so I hope it works the way I think it will